# Bootstrap 3: How to use custom container width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, the container width for large device is set to 1170px. I want to change this to a higher value such as 1500px. Can I simply change the width of `.container` to 1500px or is it going have side effects in other elements? Do I also have to change the widths of the container for medium and small devices? How do I ensure it does not break my design?

Comment: Add a custom CSS file, override the default implementations and try it out for yourself. Keep in mind that you need to focus on specific media queries or you will change the size for every instance on every screen, as well as making your selectors specific enough to overwrite the default Bootstrap behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Download a copy of Bootstrap from [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and modify the this line on [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less)

```
@container-large-desktop:      ((1140px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

to your liking:

```
@container-large-desktop:      ((1500px + @grid-gutter-width));
```

If you are not familiar with LESS, read up on it [here](http://lesscss.org/) and compile bootstrap.css file with a LESS compiler such as [Koala](http://koala-app.com/)

Comment: There is also a sass version of bootstrap! https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 2):

Definitely don't change the `.container` width inline, as that will cut-off on smaller screens. Easiest is to add this to your css:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1470px;
  }
}
```

When a screen is 1500px and up, your container will fill it, but it won't make any difference to screens/browser windows between 1200px and 1500px, or smaller.

Here's a [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/Py7RxulVc2)

ps - my Bootply is set to ~1400px because that's how wide my MBPr is - pretty common max width.

Comment: NOTE: @PETE TNT's answer is more true to intended bootstrap use, but mine is easier depending on your knowledge of LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 0):

Download bootstrap directly from thier main website http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes and customize it as you wish. The url i provided you takes you directly to the container size section and all you have to do is to change it and after that download the bootstrap files.